# Reducing or removing autocorrelation in spatially correlated data

Tags: autocorrelation, normalization, sparsity, r, spatial

I am trying to figure out how one can reduce or preferably remove autocorrelation in spatially correlated data. Using the R code below, one generates spatially correlated data that is normally distributed. How can then one eliminate autocorrelation (corr = 0.7) whilst maintaining normality?

n = 100

X = rnorm(n)

sigma = diag(n)

corr = 0.7

sigma <- corr ^ abs(row(sigma)-col(sigma))

Y <- t(X %*% chol(sigma))

Comment: what about the signal do you need to preserve? The "trivial" answer to your question would be "replace with white gaussian process", because that would completely remove all correlation and give normality. It would also remove all that you might have cared about in the original signal.

Comment: Thank you Marcus. I want to preserve almost all of the characteristics of the "spatial data" except for the autocorrelation which I intend to eliminate.  When you say "replace with the white gaussian process", do you mean replacing the "x<-rnorm(n)? or it is a completely different approach

Comment: Please tell us what properties you mean. Thank you!

Comment: I have two preferable goals, (1) given any degree of correlation (corr), I want to reduce the autocorrelation so that they can be weak dependency (i.e., less autocorrelation), or (2) to totally eliminate the autocorrelation. All this should be done using spatially correlated data. Regarding your question, I think I was wrong to say preserve the properties. There are no properties or characteristics to preserve but rather reduce or eliminate autocorrelation. Thank you

Comment: yes, but as said, if you want a signal without autocorrelation and care about nothing else, simply generate one, and ignore the one that has correlation. What's the thing that you care about that stops you from doing this?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do. The classical empirical likelihood makes the assumption or rather works well when the data is i.i.d. When the data is now correlated it is then recommended to use the blockwise empirical likelihood method which handles weakly dependent data well. I then intend to develop a test where one inputs some correlated data, then the test should be able to reduce or eliminate the correlation before applying the suitable empirical likelihood method.

Comment: again, you're not answering the question: what is it about your original signal that makes you care about it? Why not blindly discard it and use an uncorrelated one?